# How can I read from a text file

Tags: c++, text-files

I have a text file with two lines each containing a number of integers separated by a space.  How could I read each int a vector with each line being a different vector?

For example the textfile contains:

1 2 5 8 12 23 9 100 -4

4 8 5 4 8 43 9 7 1 2 5

And I would like to read from this text file storing each int in a vector but each line in a different vector so vec1 and vec2.

Comment: A good question! What did your C++ Standard Library reference say?

Comment: Nothing which is why I am asking here.

Comment: Using getline and >> operator but I can't figure out how to separate the lines.  Into two different vectors but I cannot separate the lines.

Comment: Show your code and someone will likely help. Without a minimal example the question will be closed.

Comment: ***Nothing which is why I am asking here*** You must not understand what you have read or you are reading the wrong material.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ read file array" or "c++ read file vector".  Always search first.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the number of integers in a loop and can read integers in two different vectors.

Here is a simple code

```
for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
{
  infile>>x;
  vectorObject1[x];

}

for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
{
  infile>>x;
  vectorObject2[x];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the exact number of elements in the sequence, you may read the whole line first and then put it into `istringstream`. Like in this example:

```
vector<int> a[2];
for(int i=0; i<2; ++i) {
    string buf;
    getline(cin, buf);
    istringstream iss(buf);
    a[i].insert(a[i].end(),
                std::istream_iterator<int>( iss ),
                std::istream_iterator<int>());
}
```

Comment: You're using a C-style array of `vector`? Why?

Comment: @tadman because in this case it does exactly what is needed, and does'nt do anything beyond it. But, anyway, this discussion suits more for codereview site, and here on SO it's up to TS to decide what to use.